# Probability two splits make triangle

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

This is a slight variation on the usual broken stick problem.

A stick is broken randomly into two pieces. The larger piece is then broken in two. What is the probability the pieces can form a triangle?

I take the stick as the interval $(0,1)$ and the first break as a uniform random variable $X$. Then let $Y$ be a uniform random variable on $(0,X)$. It suffices to look at $X≥1/2$ and multiply the answer by $2$. Now we want to compute the probability that $Y≤1/2$ and $X−Y≤1/2$.

My problem is that I get a probability involving $X$ so I am clearly doing something wrong, specifically I end up with $\frac{1}{4 X^2}$ ...

Comment: You want the probability that the larger part of the larger stick is less than half the length of the original stick.  What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I take the stick as the interval (0,1) and the first break as a uniform random variable X. Then let Y be a uniform random variable on (0,X). It suffices to look at $X \geq 1/2$ and multiply the answer by 2. Now we want to compute the probability that $Y \leq 1/2$ and $X -Y \leq 1/2$. My problem is that I get a probability involving X so I am clearly doing something wrong

Comment: So what do you get for the joint probability that $Y≤1/2$ and $X−Y≤1/2$?  You could then multiply this by the density for $X$ and integrate between $\frac12$ and $1$

Comment: I get $1/(4X^2)$ for the probability ...

Comment: Given $X=x\ge \frac12$, I get $\frac1x-1$  for the joint probability that $Y≤1/2$ and $X−Y≤1/2$.  This makes sense as it gives $1$ when $x=\frac12$ and $0$ when $x=1$

Answer (score 1):

The diagram below shows the relevant regions in the $X$-$Y$ plane. We uniformly choose $X\gt\frac12$ and then choose $Y\lt X$, yielding the shaded region. The region with the darker shade is the part where both $Y\lt\frac12$ and $X-Y\lt\frac12$. Given $X=x$, the proportion of the darker shade is $\frac{1-x}x=\frac1x-1$ (as Henry noted in a comment).  Averaging this over $x$ yields the probability

$$
2\int_\frac12^1\left(\frac1x-1\right)\mathrm dx=2\left[\log x-x\right]_\frac12^1=\log4-1\approx39\%\;.
$$

[image]